# How to use AJAX to check if user is still logged-in?

Tags: ajax

I am working with Wordpress 3.8

I have an app that I would like to use AJAX to check with Wordpress to determine if their idle time has expired.

In my functions.php, I have the following hook that checks when someone requests a page:

```
function cookie_expiration( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ) { echo 'ck time';
    return $remember ? $expiration : 600;// 10 minutes
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'cookie_expiration', 99, 3 );
```

This works fine when someone requests a page.

Here is the function that is called by the AJAX:

```
wp_validate_auth_cookie();
            exit(json_encode(array('result' => is_user_logged_in())));
```

I'm guessing the problem is that the AJAX call does not have the accompanying cookie with it.

So how can I check to see if an idle user has been idle too long using an AJAX call?

Comment: do you call the function with the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)?

Comment: Yes. The function is being called, and a result is being returned. The issue, I believe, is that when you make an AJAX call, the cookie info is not sent, so I think the wp_validate_auth_cookie() function is unable to determine if the time has expired.